DetectDragGestures on HorizontalPager
I have HorizontalPager with Images inside of swipeable card.
Here's how it looks

And you can swipe those cards like this.

The issue is when I'm pressing down on horizontal pager it intercepts all drag gestures, I want to be able to swipe it on overscroll. If I'm on the first image - swipe to the left should be enabled, and if I'm on the last one -> swipe to the right.
Here is the code of horizontal pager with swipe modifier:
Card(
        modifier = modifier
            .swipableCard(
                state = swipeState,
                onSwiped = {
                    when (it) {
                        Direction.Left -> onLeftSwipe()
                        Direction.Right -> onRightSwipe()
                        else -> {}
                    }
                },
                blockedDirections = listOf(Direction.Up, Direction.Down)
            ),
        colors = CardDefaults.elevatedCardColors(containerColor = MaterialTheme.colors.surface),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            PostCardInfoUi(
                post = post,
                onDescriptionClicked = onDescriptionClicked,
                onOwnProfileClicked = onOwnProfileClicked,
                onOtherProfileClicked = onOtherProfileClicked,
                pagerState = pagerState
            )
            ReactionOverlay(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                isLike = swipeState.offset.value.x > 0,
                alpha = (absoluteOffsetDp.value / 100).coerceAtLeast(0f)
            )
        }
    }

And here is swipe modifier itself with all related code
fun Modifier.swipableCard(
    state: SwipeableCardState,
    onSwiped: (Direction) -> Unit,
    onSwipeCancel: () -> Unit = {},
    blockedDirections: List<Direction> = listOf(Direction.Up, Direction.Down),
) = pointerInput(key1 = pagerPage, key2 = pagerCoordsRect) {
    coroutineScope {
        detectDragGestures(
            onDragCancel = {
                launch {
                    state.reset()
                    onSwipeCancel()
                }
            },
            onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                launch {
                    Log.i("SwipableCard", "Drag amount: $dragAmount")
                    val original = state.offset.targetValue
                    val summed = original + dragAmount
                    val newValue = Offset(
                        x = summed.x.coerceIn(-state.maxWidth, state.maxWidth),
                        y = summed.y.coerceIn(-state.maxHeight, state.maxHeight)
                    )
                    if (change.positionChange() != Offset.Zero) change.consume()
                    state.drag(newValue.x, newValue.y)
                }
            },
            onDragEnd = {
                launch {
                    val coercedOffset = state.offset.targetValue
                        .coerceIn(
                            blockedDirections,
                            maxHeight = state.maxHeight,
                            maxWidth = state.maxWidth
                        )

                    if (hasNotTravelledEnough(state, coercedOffset)) {
                        state.reset()
                        onSwipeCancel()
                    } else {
                        val horizontalTravel = abs(state.offset.targetValue.x)
                        val verticalTravel = abs(state.offset.targetValue.y)

                        if (horizontalTravel > verticalTravel) {
                            if (state.offset.targetValue.x > 0) {
                                state.swipe(Direction.Right)
                                onSwiped(Direction.Right)
                            } else {
                                state.swipe(Direction.Left)
                                onSwiped(Direction.Left)
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (state.offset.targetValue.y < 0) {
                                state.swipe(Direction.Up)
                                onSwiped(Direction.Up)
                            } else {
                                state.swipe(Direction.Down)
                                onSwiped(Direction.Down)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            )
    }
}.graphicsLayer {
    translationX = state.offset.value.x
    translationY = state.offset.value.y
    rotationZ = (state.offset.value.x / 60).coerceIn(-40f, 40f)
}


private fun Offset.coerceIn(
    blockedDirections: List<Direction>,
    maxHeight: Float,
    maxWidth: Float,
): Offset {
    return copy(
        x = x.coerceIn(
            if (blockedDirections.contains(Direction.Left)) {
                0f
            } else {
                -maxWidth
            },
            if (blockedDirections.contains(Direction.Right)) {
                0f
            } else {
                maxWidth
            }
        ),
        y = y.coerceIn(
            if (blockedDirections.contains(Direction.Up)) {
                0f
            } else {
                -maxHeight
            },
            if (blockedDirections.contains(Direction.Down)) {
                0f
            } else {
                maxHeight
            }
        )
    )
}

private fun hasNotTravelledEnough(
    state: SwipeableCardState,
    offset: Offset,
): Boolean {
    return abs(offset.x) < state.maxWidth / 4 &&
            abs(offset.y) < state.maxHeight / 4
}

enum class Direction {
    Left, Right, Up, Down
}

@Composable
fun rememberSwipeableCardState(): SwipeableCardState {
    val screenWidth = with(LocalDensity.current) {
        LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp.toPx()
    }
    val screenHeight = with(LocalDensity.current) {
        LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.dp.toPx()
    }
    return remember {
        SwipeableCardState(screenWidth, screenHeight)
    }
}


class SwipeableCardState(
    internal val maxWidth: Float,
    internal val maxHeight: Float,
) {
    val offset = Animatable(offset(0f, 0f), Offset.VectorConverter)

    /**
     * The [Direction] the card was swiped at.
     *
     * Null value means the card has not been swiped fully yet.
     */
    var swipedDirection: Direction? by mutableStateOf(null)
        private set

    internal suspend fun reset() {
        offset.animateTo(offset(0f, 0f), tween(400))
    }

    suspend fun swipe(direction: Direction, animationSpec: AnimationSpec<Offset> = tween(400)) {
        val endX = maxWidth * 1.5f
        val endY = maxHeight
        when (direction) {
            Direction.Left -> offset.animateTo(offset(x = -endX), animationSpec)
            Direction.Right -> offset.animateTo(offset(x = endX), animationSpec)
            Direction.Up -> offset.animateTo(offset(y = -endY), animationSpec)
            Direction.Down -> offset.animateTo(offset(y = endY), animationSpec)
        }
        this.swipedDirection = direction
    }

    private fun offset(x: Float = offset.value.x, y: Float = offset.value.y): Offset {
        return Offset(x, y)
    }

    internal suspend fun drag(x: Float, y: Float) {
        offset.animateTo(offset(x, y))
    }
}

What I've tried:
I've tried to write my own detectDragGestures extension function and passed HorizontalPager coordinates to it with current page state(first, middle, last), but couldn't make it, If I consume awaitFirstDown() pointer input, pager doesn't get it and doesn't move, If I wait for touchSlop to pass to decide what to do (swipe pager or swipe card) based on positionChange() direction and position coordinates, horizontal pager consumes awaitFirstDown() pointer and drag of the card doesn't happen.
-


If I consume awaitFirstDown() pointer input, pager doesn't get it and
doesn't move

Drag and scroll check awaitFirstDown with requireUnconsumed false and because of that the statement above is not true, you can't prevent drag or scroll commencing by consuming awaitFirstDown event. Consuming awaitPointerEvent stops scroll or drag, and by doing so you can stop HorizontalPager scrolling but in your case it's not even required to stop scrolling because you look for overscroll on first page and last page.
Drag source code
internal suspend fun PointerInputScope.detectDragGestures(
    onDragStart:
        (
            down: PointerInputChange, slopTriggerChange: PointerInputChange, overSlopOffset: Offset
        ) -> Unit,
    onDragEnd: (change: PointerInputChange) -> Unit,
    onDragCancel: () -> Unit,
    shouldAwaitTouchSlop: () -> Boolean,
    orientationLock: Orientation?,
    onDrag: (change: PointerInputChange, dragAmount: Offset) -> Unit
) {
    var overSlop: Offset

    awaitEachGesture {
        val initialDown = awaitFirstDown(requireUnconsumed = false, pass = PointerEventPass.Initial)
        val awaitTouchSlop = shouldAwaitTouchSlop()

        if (!awaitTouchSlop) {
            initialDown.consume()
        }
        val down = awaitFirstDown(requireUnconsumed = false)
        var drag: PointerInputChange?
        overSlop = Offset.Zero

        if (awaitTouchSlop) {
            do {
                drag =
                    awaitPointerSlopOrCancellation(
                        down.id,
                        down.type,
                        orientation = orientationLock
                    ) { change, over ->
                        change.consume()
                        overSlop = over
                    }
            } while (drag != null && !drag.isConsumed)
        } else {
            drag = initialDown
        }

        if (drag != null) {
            onDragStart.invoke(down, drag, overSlop)
            onDrag(drag, overSlop)
            val upEvent =
                drag(
                    pointerId = drag.id,
                    onDrag = {
                        onDrag(it, it.positionChange())
                        it.consume()
                    },
                    orientation = orientationLock,
                    motionConsumed = { it.isConsumed }
                )
            if (upEvent == null) {
                onDragCancel()
            } else {
                onDragEnd(upEvent)
            }
        }
    }
}

awaitPointerSlopOrCancellation checks consumed first then in Final pass this is where you can't pass since scroll consumes it, the part dragEvent.isConsumed it happens
private suspend inline fun AwaitPointerEventScope.awaitPointerSlopOrCancellation(
    pointerId: PointerId,
    pointerType: PointerType,
    orientation: Orientation?,
    onPointerSlopReached: (PointerInputChange, Offset) -> Unit,
): PointerInputChange? {
    if (currentEvent.isPointerUp(pointerId)) {
        return null // The pointer has already been lifted, so the gesture is canceled
    }
    val touchSlop = viewConfiguration.pointerSlop(pointerType)
    var pointer: PointerId = pointerId
    val touchSlopDetector = TouchSlopDetector(orientation)
    while (true) {
        val event = awaitPointerEvent()
        val dragEvent = event.changes.fastFirstOrNull { it.id == pointer } ?: return null
        if (dragEvent.isConsumed) {
            return null
        } else if (dragEvent.changedToUpIgnoreConsumed()) {
            val otherDown = event.changes.fastFirstOrNull { it.pressed }
            if (otherDown == null) {
                // This is the last "up"
                return null
            } else {
                pointer = otherDown.id
            }
        } else {
            val postSlopOffset = touchSlopDetector.addPointerInputChange(dragEvent, touchSlop)
            if (postSlopOffset.isSpecified) {
                onPointerSlopReached(dragEvent, postSlopOffset)
                if (dragEvent.isConsumed) {
                    return dragEvent
                } else {
                    touchSlopDetector.reset()
                }
            } else {
                // verify that nothing else consumed the drag event
                awaitPointerEvent(PointerEventPass.Final)
                if (dragEvent.isConsumed) {
                    return null
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

If checking for slop or threshold is not an issue you can write a down, move and up gesture as mentioned in this answer. The difference between checking awaitTouchSlopOrCancellation and drag in original source code of detectDragGestures check if they are consumed but you don't have to and that you can get events. Also, unlike detectDragGestures which already calls consume() in onDrag you can conditionally call it as well.
By the way, calling change.consume() in onDrag has no effect because drag already calls it.
private fun Modifier.customTouch(
    pass: PointerEventPass = PointerEventPass.Main,
    onDown: (pointer: PointerInputChange) -> Unit,
    onMove: (changes: List<PointerInputChange>) -> Unit,
    onUp: () -> Unit,
) = this.then(
    Modifier.pointerInput(pass) {
        awaitEachGesture {
            val down = awaitFirstDown(pass = pass)
            onDown(down)
            do {
                val event: PointerEvent = awaitPointerEvent(
                    pass = pass
                )

                onMove(event.changes)

            } while (event.changes.any { it.pressed })
            onUp()
        }
    }
)

And check how consuming down or move changes HorizontalPager scroll status with
@Preview
@Composable
fun PagerConsumeTest() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {

        val pagerState = rememberPagerState { 5 }

        var text by remember {
            mutableStateOf("")
        }

        var consumeDown by remember {
            mutableStateOf(false)
        }

        var consumeMove by remember {
            mutableStateOf(false)
        }
        Text(text, fontSize = 20.sp, modifier = Modifier.height(90.dp))

        CheckBoxWithTextRippleFullRow(
            label = "consumeDown",
            state = consumeDown,
            onStateChange = {
                consumeDown = it
            }
        )

        CheckBoxWithTextRippleFullRow(
            label = "consumeMove",
            state = consumeMove,
            onStateChange = {
                consumeMove = it
            }
        )

        HorizontalPager(
            modifier = Modifier
                .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
                .customTouch(
                    onDown = { pointer ->
                        text = " onDown() id: ${pointer.id}\n" +
                                "consumed: ${pointer.isConsumed}\n" +
                                "position: ${pointer.position}\n"

                        if (consumeDown) {
                            pointer.consume()
                        }
                    },
                    onMove = { changes ->
                        changes.firstOrNull()?.let {
                            text = " onMove() id: ${it.id}\n" +
                                    "consumed: ${it.isConsumed}\n" +
                                    "position: ${it.position}\n"
                        }

                        if (consumeMove) {
                            changes.forEach { it.consume() }
                        }
                    },
                    onUp = {
                        text = "top onUp()"
                    }
                ),
            state = pagerState
        ) { page ->
            Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
                Text("Page: $page", fontSize = 36.sp)
            }
        }
    }
}


By using this gesture you can drag or move, prevent scroll and with pass you can change if it receives events first and apply your logic successfully.
If you want to implement your custom drag you can modify with
1- A flag to requireUnconsumed for awaitPointerEvent
2- A flag whether you want slop control or not, in pagers, it can scroll till slop threshold is passed
3- And a PointerEventPass to change propagation direction
I built custom drag that takes these parameters, and also planning to add it to gesture library when i'm available.
And made some samples with it including one below for removing Composable on swipe from left to right on first page only.
And with params set as
detectDragGesture(
    requireUnconsumed = true,
    shouldAwaitTouchSlop = true,
    pass = PointerEventPass.Initial,

it get events before or check it requires event to be not consumed or doesn't have to wait for slope pass if not needed

https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials/blob/master/Tutorial1-1Basics/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/tutorial1_1basics/chapter5_gesture/Tutorital5_16DragHorizontalPager.kt

As you can see in last example, even if it drags same direction with scroll, scroll doesn't happen. Only drag happens because i conditionally consume inside onDrag unlike default drag gesture which already consumes whether you call consume or not

I wasn't hoping for somebody to actually put so much effort into the answer, thank you so much! I used your custom detectDragGesture() method and I was able to achieve desired behavior with shouldAwaitTouchSlop=false. I was playing around with this function; I have put logs here and there to have more understanding of what is actually happening, and it seems like drag returned null in awaitTouchSlopOrCancellation because it was consumed in PointerEventPass.Main. But when I pass PointerEventPass.Initial to it, horizontal pager stops scrolling, although I don't consume scroll anywhere.

I don't think scroll stops if you don't consume it. Initial changes only propagation direction. You can check DragPagerTest example in my tutorial with Initial pass but you should remove consume inside onDrag.

"it seems like drag returned null in awaitTouchSlopOrCancellation because it was consumed in PointerEventPass.Main." This is true, scroll consumes it and in first check for consumed in awaitPointerSlopOrCancellation returns null that's why drag doesn't happen with default detectDragGestures

scroll for pager not happening specifically If I pass shouldAwaitTouchSlop = true to your detectDragGesture() function and PointerEventPass.Initial to awaitTouchSlopOrCancellation() function inside of detectDragGesture(). You can try it yourself! Wow, you started this tag? I never thought I would come across such a celebrity on Stack Overflow =)

I tested it now and that's correct because awaitTouchSlopOrCancellation also calls consume as you can see. I also had tried removing that consume for inspecting why they consume it and it didn't work well because it resets touchSlopDetector

And i had removed initial from awaitTouchSlopOrCancellation and put it back. I wonder which behavior is better. I think adding pass to it is correct behavior since changing pass also should stop scroll the moment slop check happens

https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/gestures/DragGestureDetector.kt;drc=f14d537cb16b9d92d506bfcdd179d0f4519924a2;l=259 line it happens if you use initial in awaitTouchSlopOrCancellation. Since i removed it earlier, and Main pass for slope check happens after scroll it wasn't stopping scroll here

So to sum up, if we set shouldAwaitTouchSlop = true and pass PointerEventPass.Initial to awaitTouchSlopOrCancellation function, scroll will be consumed by the line you mentioned (we can't remove it, because it resets touchSlopDetector) and Horizontal Pager won't be scrolling. And if we pass PointerEventPass.Main to awaitTouchSlopOrCancellation(), drag will be null (consumed by pager) and card dragging won't happen. So, the only way to achieve behavior mentioned in this topic is pass shouldAwaitTouchSlop = false?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
